# How to read the content from tar file in lambda function in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I want to read content which is inside of a .tar file without extracting the tar file. I tried my local machine and successfully, I am able to read the content of the file. Just, I passed the path of the .tar file. For doing this I used one library called **tarfile**. With the help of this library I did it. Now I am trying to do same in AWS using the lambda function but I am not able to do it. Can you suggest any alternative for that ?

```
import tarfile
file_path = r'C:/Users/xyz/Downloads/abc.tar'
tar = tarfile.open(file_path, "r:gz")
for member in tar.getnames():
    name = str(member) 
    if name.endswith(".txt"):
        f = tar.extractfile(name)
        if f:
            for i in f:
                print(str(i))
```

Code for the AWS

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
Bucket='abc-logs'
if event:
        for i in event:
            file_obj = event["Records"][0]
            Key = str(file_obj['s3']['object']['key'])
            if file_name_split == 'PERFORMANCE':
                print("Key",Key)
                tar_file_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='abc-logs',Key=Key)
                # print(tar_file_obj)
                # tar = tarfile.open(tar_file_obj["Body"],"r:gz")
                # print(tar)
                file_content = tar_file_obj["Body"].iter_lines()
                print(file_content)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read tar file content with the following approach:

```
tar_file_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='abc-logs',Key=Key)
tar_content = tar_file_obj ['Body'].read()

with tarfile.open(fileobj = BytesIO(tar_content)) as tar:
   for tar_resource in tar:
      if (tar_resource.isfile()):
         inner_file_bytes = tar.extractfile(tar_resource).read()
```

Comment: This answer worked great for me except that line 2 should actually be 'tar_content = tar_file_obj.get()['Body'].read()'.